# displaying button in android by nesting views

Tags: android

**I have xml code of button**
it has single text

```
               <Button
                android:id="@+id/BuyButton"
                android:layout_width="81sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="buy" />
```

**But how to make the above button as::**

[image]

Clearly there are two text in button .... how to nest two text in a single button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
        android:layout_width="81dp"
        android:layout_height="81dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="buy" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Price" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer is informative but whole thing(with both views) should be button ... any ideas

Comment: could you pls elaborate

Comment: you paste this code in eclipse and watch the difference, it will view like a button not like a view, check out!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
android:text="Buy \n Price"
```

Comment: What if i want two seperate text views inside a button .... Why i am asking is in future I am putting the value for **Buy** from database so .... any ideas

Comment: @Sky If you are thinking to make it dynamic then you can generate a String at run time and can display the same in Button using `setText()` method.

Comment: Yes ...... but check out the answer from one of the answers for this question from person called exceptional ... is it feasable insted of button

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BuyButton"
            android:layout_width="81sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="buy \n Price" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/icon">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Buy" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Price" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am refering to textviews inside a button

Comment: `Exception raised during rendering: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup` will occur if you reffer textviews inside a button

Comment: Ok so how to display the text inside button from database ?

Comment: if u are using single button instead two textview then: `in Class file: button1.setText(DataFromDB+"\nPrice");`

Answer (score 0):

try this..
after two lines price will come

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/BuyButton"
            android:layout_width="81sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="buy \n \n price" />
```

Comment: What if i want two seperate text views inside a button .... Why i am asking is in future I am putting the value for **Buy** from database so .... any ideas